# /fill with blocks added by a mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, mods, minecraft-forge

In Minecraft Java edition, I am using a mod (with Forge 1.12.2) that adds [colored water](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/colorfulwater). I want to `/fill` a region with colored water, but don't know the name of the block.

Usually, when I don't know the name of a block, I look at the block using the debug screen (F3). Here is the debug screen in Minecraft 1.13. I'm looking at water, as the screen indicates (where the green arrow points). It also tells me that the block below the water is quartz (immediately above the green arrow).

[image]

But when I play with Forge, it doesn't show the names of fluids. Here is the debug screen in Minecraft with Forge 1.12.2. I'm looking at water, again, but note how the screen only indicates the block below the water:

[image]

**How can I find the name of a block that has been added by a mod?**

The name shown when I select the block in the inventory ("Glowing White Water"), and the name of the block in the mod source code ("glowing_water_white"), both don't work.

Or can I not use the `/fill` command with mod-added blocks?

Comment: It's likely that the different colors of water aren't actually their own blocks, but instead a subvalue of a single base colored water block.

Comment: @SaintWacko That assumes it's version 1.12 or earlier, which seems to be the case for Forge.  Going forward, I would assume most Forge mods will use the current paradigm of every block getting their own block and item IDs, and then grouping those blocks and items with tags.

Comment: If i remember well with WorldEdit to use Subvalues you need to do something like //fill blockid : blocksubvalue
So probably something like //fill water:2

Comment: I would have suggested `/testfor`, one of the rare cases where it's useful (replaced with feedback from `execute if block` in 1.13), but that uses translated names. You could probably extract the jar file for the mod, look at the default language resource and search for the translated name, but that's a lot of effort, I don't know whether that's worth it. In 1.13 you can just press F3+I.

Answer (score 1):

*Thank you for that comment, @Reivilox.*

The mod id is 'colored_water', one of the blocks is named 'glowing_water_green', and you can `/fill` with this block using:

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 colored_water:glowing_water_green
```

Comment: Ah, good, I figured that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured this out on my own so here's an example from the Chisel mod: `chisel:basalt2 1` so basically you `/fill cord cord cord` and then the name of the mod with this. In my case it would look like `chisel:` then the name of the block and whatever variation of that block it is.